# why we get error with making new file in spyder code editor

Tags: python, spyder

why spyder code editor gives us error when we make another file in it.error?

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Pouria/untitled0.py'.

how to solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Could you upload a screenshot of how Spyder looks when you get that error?